# jQuery Animation not stopping

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, infinite-loop

I tried everything I could find. Basically this jQuery is for a nav, when you hover over an item a picture fades in and out. How do i get the first animation to stop, it doesn't let the other animations work. Or what would be a better way to code this animation

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                 $('.navImage').stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 400, function(){   });


                $('.nav-container li').hover(function(){
                    var name = $(this).attr("id");

                    $('img.'+name).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 'toggle'
                      }, 400 ); 
                }); 
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
).stop(true, true).animate(...
```

As you can see at http://api.jquery.com/stop/ this will clear the queue and jump to the end of it, hopefully actually stopping the animation.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work, maybe it has something to do with $(document).read(, maybe it keeps running that code

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't be the reason. $(document).ready just happens when the document has loaded.